# %like% search suddenly slows down when datasize increases

Tags: postgresql

I have a SQL that searches words from the string column. 
The column has indexes that enable Intermediate Matching via pg_trgm extensions.

```
CREATE INDEX index ON "Texts" USING gist (body gist_trgm_ops);
SELECT * FROM "Texts" WHERE body like '%hogehoge%';
```

When the following conditions, text search works well.

```
Table size : 34 MB
Index size : 722 MB
-> Total runtime :  1.03 sec
```

But, when I increase the amount of data, the response significantly slows down.

```
Table size : 42 MB 
Index size : 1321 MB
-> Total runtime : 91.38 sec
```

I changed "shared_buffers" to keep up with the index size, but it didn't change the response time.
Are there any ideas to let the response faster?

> [Server specs]
>    -OS         : Windows Server 2012 R2
>    -Memory Size: 4GB
>   [postgresql.conf settings]
>     -effective_cache_size : 3145383kB
>     -shared_buffers       : 1228MB -> 2228MB
>     -work_mem             : 6290kB
>   [Versions]
>    PostgreSQL 9.2.4

**[edit]**
Results of EXPLAIN ANALYZE are below.(Table size is not the same as above, but  the response time is unnaturally slow too.)

normal:http://explain.depesz.com/s/cUk

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on "Texts"  (cost=31.01..69.08 rows=10 width=139) (actual time=1515.342..1568.444 rows=999 loops=1)"
  Recheck Cond: ((text_body)::text ~~ '%hogehoge%'::text)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on Texts_index  (cost=0.00..31.00 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=1514.642..1514.642 rows=999 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((text_body)::text ~~ '%hogehoge%'::text)
Total runtime: 1573.718 ms
```

slower:http://explain.depesz.com/s/u7O

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on "Texts"  (cost=88.46..204.18 rows=30 width=139) (actual time=406272.437..427309.329 rows=2999 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((text_body)::text ~~ '%hogehoge%'::text)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on texts_index  (cost=0.00..88.46 rows=30 width=0) (actual time=406241.142..406241.142 rows=2999 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((text_body)::text ~~ '%hogehoge%'::text)
Total runtime: 427419.800 ms
```

**[edit2]**
Thanks for your comments. I tried below, but neither work.

- SET STATISTICS (-1 -> 10000) and ANALYZE
- Increase memory size from 4GB to 8GB

I think buffering causes the difference of the response speed.
When I retried searching after the server responded, second response was 100+ times faster.
And when I rebooted the server and executed the same SQL, the response slowed down again.

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE at http://explain.depesz.com ? Without this information it's next to impossible to help you.

Comment: run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM "Texts" WHERE body like '%hogehoge%';`

Comment: Your statistics are off. Run `analyze "Texts"` and see if that changes anything

Comment: In addition to a_horse_with_no_name's response, you might have to change the setting for the statistics as well: ALTER TABLE "Texts"     ALTER body SET STATISTICS _integer_; You have to check what _integer_  value works best for your situation